# How to create a dropdown in ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework? I have created a dropdown in view and created a list binding in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

View markup:

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
     <label>Month :</label>
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MonthId, Model.MonthList, "Please Select Month", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Month", @onchange = "fetchdata()" })
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
public List<SelectListItem> BindDropdownMonthDetails()
{
    List<SelectListItem> MonthList = (from p in financetoolentities.FinancialMonths.AsEnumerable()
                                      select new SelectListItem
                                                 {
                                                     Text = p.MonthName,
                                                     Value = p.MonthID.ToString()
                                                 }).ToList();

    return MonthList;
}
```

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'MonthId'

Comment: Need more code to help you. Need your model, ActionResult that send to the view and also a part of view that show if you are binding model...

Comment: RD.MonthList = BindDropdownMonthDetails(); i forgot  to write it in action result.